# Out-File: output file path is not accepted

Tags: powershell

Still learning and am having a hard time trying to output information to a file: the **output file path is not accepted**.

My **location is `PS Cert:\localmachine`** and here is the entire command:

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem -Path cert: -Recurse | where { $_.notafter -le (get-date).AddDays(75) -AND $_.notafter -gt (get-date)} | select notafter, issuer, thumbprint, subject | sort-object notafter
$cert | Out-File -FilePath \\ad.dcpds.cpms.osd.mil\WinAdm\Logs\Expiring_Certificates\$hostname.log
```

The **error message** I'm getting is:

`Out-File : Cannot open file because the current provider (Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate) cannot open a file.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the comments above, the issue comes from the fact that the current location is somewhere in the certificate provider (`cert:`).
One possible workaround/solution is to change the current location back to the file provider before writing the file.

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem -Path cert: -Recurse | where { $_.notafter -le (get-date).AddDays(75) -AND $_.notafter -gt (get-date)} | select notafter, issuer, thumbprint, subject | sort-object notafter
Set-location c:
$cert | out-file -FilePath \\ad.dcpds.cpms.osd.mil\WinAdm\Logs\Expiring_Certificates\$h‌​ostname.log
```

Second solution: use a path that explicitly includes the filesystem provider:

```
$cert | out-file -FilePath FileSystem::\\ad.dcpds.cpms.osd.mil\WinAdm\Logs\Expiring_Certificates\$h‌​ostname.log
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement [PoorKenny's effective solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39416693/45375) with background information:

**If you use `Out-File` and the *current location* is on a drive of a provider OTHER than the *filesystem* provider**:

- **only *drive letter-based paths* are recognized as filesystem paths**; e.g.:

  - `... | Out-File C:\temp\out.txt  # OK, due to using filesystem drive C:`
- ***any other path* requires prefix `FileSystem::`**, notably including paths such as `\path\to\...` and even `\\server\share\path\to\...` (UNC paths); without the prefix, they're interpreted as relative to the current location, whatever its provider, which fails for any provider other than the filesystem provider.

  - `... | Out-File \temp\out.txt  # NOT recognized`
  - `... | Out-File \\server\share\temp\out.txt  # NOT recognized`
  - `... | Out-File FileSystem::\temp\out.txt  # OK, thanks to 'FileSystem::' prefix`

**Arguably, given that `Out-File` only ever creates *files*, it would make sense to ALWAYS interpret the `-FilePath` / `-LiteralPath` arguments as a *filesystem* path, *irrespective of the provider of the current location*.**

However, the following, from an example that comes with the [`Out-File` help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13d09dc8-2398-4d73-9449-1d01eb4e7808(v=wps.650).aspx), suggests that the behavior is *by design* (the (omitted) example invokes `Out-File` from a current location on the *registry provider's* drive).

> Because Out-File is not supported by the Windows PowerShell Registry provider, you must specify either the file system drive name, such as c:, or the name of the provider followed by two colons, FileSystem::, in the value of the FilePath parameter.
>   "

If anyone knows whether there truly is a good reason *not* to always default to the *filesystem* provider's current location, do let us know.
(Can there be additional, alternative *filesystem* providers?).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Also SCCM creates a file system provider that resembles your SCCM site code.

Comment: Thanks, @RoYoMi - but can you actually create _files_ in a SCCM drive? What happens if you run something like `'hi' > t.txt` there?